# Adding the integer 0 as a value of key in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, integer, nsmutabledictionary, null

I'm creating a dictionary `NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`
and want to assign 0 to it as a valid integer value like so: `parameters[@"size"] = 0;` but since the value of `nil/NULL` is 0 i get the following warning: `"Value stored into 'NSMutableDictionary' cannot be nil"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `@0` instead of `0`

Comment: @godel9 thanks, what does the @ mean when it's not before a string? what other implementations does it have

Comment: @liva The `@` means that the compiler will turn the `0` into an `NSNumber` object representing `0`, allowing it to be stored in arrays and dictionaries. This is the same as `@"Hello"` turning into an `NSString` at compile-time. There's a good section on object literals [on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/).

Comment: The value must be an OBJECT.  You can't use a bare integer value, whether zero or 837450126.  Either use an NSNumber or an NSString.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your integer as a `NSNumber` with `@(0)` (or `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]`). This converts your integer value into an object that can be added to `NSMutableDictionary` or any other collection.

Just make sure to unwrap the dictionary value with `NSInteger value = [wrappedNumber integerValue]` before doing your comparisons.

Comment: Numeric literals don't require parentheses -- that syntax if for numeric *expressions*. `@0` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I personally find parenthesis wrapping number easier to read despite it is *optional*.

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

parameters[@"size"] = @(0);
NSInteger sizeInt = [parameters[@"size"] integerValue];
```